# Passing args and kwargs to another funtion

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I have a GUI I'd like to run some function with `QThreadpool`

```
class GUI(QMainWindow)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   
        ...

        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.start_process)

        ...
    
    def start_process(self):
        worker = TestWorker(self.split_csv)  # Any other args, kwargs are passed to the run function
        worker.signals.result.connect(self.print_output)
        worker.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_complete)
        worker.signals.progress.connect(self.progress_fn)


    def split_csv(self, progress_callback):
        for n in range(0, 5):
            time.sleep(1)
            progress_callback.emit(n * 100 / 4)

        return "Done."
```

Which work perfectly fine.

However, I'd like to pass some arguments  to `split_csv`

```
def split_csv(self, progress_callback, size: int, contracts_path: str, total_contracts: int):
```

but I cannot get it to work.

I tried:

```
    def start_process(self):
        worker = TestWorker(self.run_split)
        ...

    def run_split(self):
        self.split_csv(
            size=int(self.txtChunks.text()),
            contracts_path=self.__contracts_path,
            total_contracts=self.__total_contracts,
            progress_callback=self.progress_fn
        )
```

and many variations (e.g. as `lambda`) but it always gives me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\xxx\TestWorker.py",
> line 44, in run
> result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) TypeError: run_split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'progress_callback'

With the TestWorker looking like this:

```
@pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        """
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        """

        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) # LINE 44
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done
```

How would I add the callback function here?

PS: Original Tutorial was found here: https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/

Comment: The problem is that `TestWorker` is passing `run_split` the arguments that are supposed to be going to `split_csv`.  Why does `run_split` even exist and why is `TestWorker` calling it?  It seems like it should just be calling `split_csv`.

Comment: I don't quite understand that tbh. `TestWorker` in my try is calling `run_split` instead of a lambda such as `l_split = lambda: self.split_csv(...)` with `TestWorker(l_split)`. However, please ignore this, if this is the wrong approach. Maybe you could look into the original question, how to pass a function WITH args to `TestWorker`? Thank you for your time!

Comment: It seems like your `TestWorker` has args but I don't see how it gets them.

Comment: You need to share your actual code.  Where's your `TestWorker`'s init?  How is it getting the args that are meant for `split_csv` (which are *also* built into `run_csv`)?  It seems like you're mixing and matching two different approaches, but it's hard to give you guidance on fixing your code without seeing the part that has the bug.

Comment: However, based on the error, I *think* all you need to do is change `worker = TestWorker(self.run_split)` to `worker=TestWorker(self.split_csv)`, and set the other `split_csv` arguments in the same place in your `TestWorker` initialization where you've already set `progress_callback`.  Delete `run_split` completely.